# Dynamic select menu's in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select, dynamic

I am trying to get dynamic select menu's working in my Rails application.

I have a model called kase, a model called person and a model called company.

When a user creates a new kase, they are presented with a select field to choose a Person and a select field to choose a Company.

I am trying to make it dynamic, so if they choose company a in the first select field then only employees of company a will be listed in the Person field.

The model associations are as follows:

```
class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company # foreign key: company_id
  belongs_to :person # foreign key in join table
  belongs_to :surveyor,
             :class_name => "Company",
             :foreign_key => "appointedsurveyor_id"
  belongs_to :surveyorperson,
             :class_name => "Person",
             :foreign_key => "surveyorperson_id"

-------------------------------------------------  

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases
  has_many :people
  def to_s; companyname; end

-------------------------------------------------

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases # foreign key in join table
  belongs_to :company
```

**UPDATED JAVASCRIPT**

```
var people = new Array();
<% for person in @people -%>
  people.push(new Array(<%= person.company_id %>, '<%=h person.personname %>', <%= person.id %>));
<% end -%>

function personSelected() {
  alert('hello world');
  appointedsurveyor_id = $('kase_appointedsurveyor_id').getValue();
  options = $('kase_surveyorperson_id').options;
  options.length = 1;
  people.each(function(person) {
    if (person[0] == appointedsurveyor_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(person[0], person[1]);
      alert('hello world')
    }
  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('kase_surveyorperson_id').hide();
  } else {
    $('kase_surveyorperson_id').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $('kase_appointedsurveyor_id').observe('change', personSelected);
});
```

Comment: I know, I'm looking at meta.stackoverflow.com now to work out how to add comments with blocks of code. Sorry!

Comment: Just edit out the old code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var people = new Array();
<% for person in @people -%>
  people.push(new Array(<%= person.id %>, '<%=h person.login %>'));
<% end -%>

function personSelected() {
  alert('hello world');
  appointedsurveyor_id = $('company_appointedsurveyor_id').getValue();
  options = $('person_appointedsurveyorperson_id').options;
  options.length = 1;
  people.each(function(person) {
    if (person[0] == appointedsurveyor_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(person[0], person[1]);
    }
  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('person_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('person_field').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  //companySelected(); << remove this
  $('person_field').observe('change', personSelected);
});
```

Comment: If I change it to person I get the following: NoMethodError in Javascripts#dynamic_people

Showing app/views/javascripts/dynamic_people.js.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `appointedsurveyor_id' for #<Person:0x105020980>

Comment: Looks like your problem stems from this. Can you explain the relationship between person, kase and company? Each person has many kases and each kase has a company?

Comment: Hi, each kase belongs to a person and each person has many kases.

Comment: Hi Danny. Person doesn't have the field appointedsurveyor_id but it does have id which in turn is used in the join. This surely is what you need to compare. Check out my edit.

Comment: Sad trombone really made me laugh. :) Couple of things, you'll need to hide the person field in the html or in a stylesheet - there's no js event to hide it, only to display it. On person_field change you're calling a function companySelected when surely it should be personSelected?

Comment: Haha - I aim to please! Ok, I display:none'd the person field, altered the personSelected. Still nothing, although obviously the person field is now hidden.
Although the javascript file is definitely loading, is there a way of seeing if it's 'finding' the field I'm trying to work with?

Comment: You could stick an alert('hello world') in the personSelected function see if it's getting fired.

Comment: $('person_field').observe('change', personSelected, alert('hello world')); - has no effect on the form page. Does that mean the two aren't linked correctly somewhere?

Comment: I meant to put the alert in the function rather than the function call:  function personSelected() { alert.... Also you should really install firefox and firebug which would likely tell you what was wrong/ :)

Comment: Hmm. Firebug is confusing me! The input ID is called "kase_appointedsurveyor_id" but I'm not sure whether to use that or the li id?

Comment: Use the input, the li doesn't have a change event. The reason it's called that is rails is adding it. No problem though, just change your event listener (observer).

Comment: Ok, so now it's as follows:

  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('kase_surveyorperson_id').hide();
  } else {
    $('kase_surveyorperson_id').show();
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  companySelected();
  $('kase_appointedsurveyor_id').observe('change', personSelected));
});

Comment: You're still calling the companySelected function which doesn't exist. Remove that as you're hiding the field in html. See my edited answer. What else happens, are you seeing the alert?

Comment: No such luck :(, updated my question with the updated javascript.

Comment: You still have the alert in the event listener. Move it into the function as my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry Mark, I really am pre-beginner with Javascript could you explain a little further. I don't know my function's from my elbow. EDIT: I have updated my Javascript with here I *think* it should be...

Comment: Hey don't worry, I'm not much ahead of you. You have a closing bracket that needs removed: $('kase_appointedsurveyor_id').observe('change', personSelected)remove>>)<<remove; Also if you look at my answer I've added the alert in the personSelected function.

Comment: Great thanks, I have updated the javascript. Interestingly/annoyingly - the Hello world doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: No, none - which is strange! - Scratch that, when I choose the company name the hello world shows, and an error that appointedsurveyor_id = $('company_appointedsurveyor_id').getValue();  is null.

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the javascript above. There are now no error, but the Hello world displays twice and then nothing changes.

Comment: haha - it's working. I left my original alert in place by accident.

Comment: D'oh - just realised it's outputting the company_id number for the people not their name :S

Comment: If you inspect the javascript which is being generated you should see where/whether the name is in the array. person[0]/person[1]/person[2]

Comment: Just checked, it definitely is: `  people.push(new Array(1, 'Person A', 1));` - is it possible to show the name rather than the company_id associated with the person? Every combination I try doesnt work.

Comment: I don't know which order you should be putting these in but:
options[options.length] = new Option(person[1], person[0]); Should be ok? You'll also need to check the value if this does work, if it's wrong then it should be Option(person[1], person[2]).

Comment: That fixed it - if you ever want to get married give me a shout because I L-O-V-E you!

Comment: Dear Friend , 
I'm very happy to meet you, my name is Glory and i am single . 
I know that God have his own way of bringing people together.I was moved to write to you and also seek your advice of which i know that it helps me to overcome my present situation,I'm presently single and searching for a trusted and God fearing person. My dearest,In your free time, may it please you to write me back so that i can explain more about myself,my details,my pictures and my purpose of writing to you. 
glorydominicsary@419mail.com 
May God bless you as i wait impatiently to read from you. 
Yours Glory. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try observe_field. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002183

Comment: There is not point in writing so much code when you have a feature available. DRY!!!